# Adding an ASP.NET MVC grid to application using PagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, gridview, pagedlist

I am trying to add a grid to a table of data in my MVC application but keep getting the following error message:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AssociateTracker.Models.Associate]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[AssociateTracker.Models.Associate]'.
```

**View:**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<AssociateTracker.Models.Associate>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewAll";
}

<h2>View all</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "ViewAll", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })</th>
        <th>Email address</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.Email</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.AssociateId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.AssociateId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AssociateId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<div>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    of @Model.PageCount
    &nbsp;
    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "ViewAll", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "ViewAll", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;");
        @:< Prev
    }
    &nbsp;
    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "ViewAll", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;");
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "ViewAll", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    }
    else
    {
        @:Next >
        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
        @:>>
    }
</div>
```

I have checked against Microsoft's [Contosos University](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) example but can't spot any differences. Can anyone else see what the issue might be?

Comment: The model that you are passing in the controller, does not match the the model you have specified in the view.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought to check my controller. That's where the problem was!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message seems pretty self explanatory. Your view expects an `IPagedList<Associate>` instance but you are passing a `List<Associate>` from your controller action.

So inside your controller action you need to provide the proper model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    List<Associate> associates = GetAssociates();
    IPagedList<Associate> model = associates.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
    return View(model);
}
```

I used the extension method [from here](https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging). The `IPagedList<T>` is not a standard type built in ASP.NET MVC so you will have to reference the proper assemblies.

Comment: As always a great answer Darin!